# Classified as/ classified into?

Tags: terminology

> 1. The level of A is classified **into** high, medium and low?
> 2. The level of A is classified **as** high, medium and low?

Which of the above is correct?

Comment: Folks, this is not a proof-reading question. It's about the correct preposition for the given verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb *classified* takes both the prepositions *into* as well as *as*. However, the preposition changes the meaning.

The phrase *classified into* is used with a hypernym or group noun followed by the elements of the group.

> People can be classified into four basic personality types: optimistic, pessimistic, trusting and envious. ([firstpost](https://www.firstpost.com/living/people-can-be-classified-into-four-basic-personality-types-says-study-3009490.html))

OTOH, *classified as* is more often used with an element of a group followed by its classification.

> The film has been classified as category III in Hong Kong, meaning it can only be shown to persons aged over 18. ([ODOL](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/classify))

However, there are common exceptions in usage.

In the OP's example, there's a list of elements, so that the preposition *into* is used: "The level of A is **classified into** high, medium and low."

As stated earlier, though, "The level of A is **classified as** high, medium and low" is also found frequently and may not be considered incorrect.

Comment: When using __as__ it would be better to link the options with an __or__ rather than an __and__, as something would not be classified as all three cases.

Comment: @NeilW With an *or*, the sentence will have the same meaning as the usual usage of the *as* preposition and not a form of the *into* structure. My (real-life) example with *and* is to show that *as* is used where *into* is normally the default.

Comment: Would 'at' be an alternative? e.g. "... classified at category III..."